# Draw inside custom Eclipse View

Tags: java, graphics, eclipse-plugin, swt, awt

I've created a custom view for my Eclipse plugin, using [this](https://eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html) tutorial. Now I want to draw something inside that view. For test purposes it just should be some lines (for example):

```
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

public class PlotterView extends ViewPart {

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {

    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

        Shell activeShell = parent.getDisplay().getActiveShell();
        GC gc = new GC(activeShell);

        gc.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
        gc.drawLine(100, 0, 0, 100);
    }
}
```

I also tried to use:

```
Display display = Display.getCurrent();
Shell activeShell = display.getActiveShell();
```

Unfortunately no lines are visible. Is it possible to draw custom shapes in a custom view? How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Use a `Canvas` control in the view. https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html

Comment: @John Must you strictly use Eclipse plugin? If not, there are many ways we can show you how to draw graphics if it is not limited to Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The active shell covers the whole of Eclipse so this is not a suitable control to draw on.

Instead add a `Canvas` object to your view and draw on that in a `PaintListener`:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE);

  canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void paintControl(final PaintEvent event)
      {
        GC gc = event.gc;

        gc.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
        gc.drawLine(100, 0, 0, 100);
      }
    });
```